# Proving inequality ${n \choose k}x^k\le (1+x)^n \le e^{xn}$

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to prove the following inequality

> $${n\choose k}x^k\le(1+x)^n\le e^{xn}$$ for $1\le k\le n$ and $0<x<1$.

**My try:**

By the binom
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}x^k$$hence, for any $1\le k\le n$ we have $\displaystyle (1+x)^n\ge{n\choose k}x^k$.

Now $\displaystyle \left(1+x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le e \Rightarrow (1+x)^n\le e^{xn}$.

Also, I need to use the above inequality in order to show that $\displaystyle {n\choose k}\le \left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k$ and that $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{k}{n\choose i}\le \left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k$.

For part 2, I think we can use $x=\frac{k}{n}$. I'm clueless about the third.

Is my reasoning for part one and two is correct? How should I tackle it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your reasoning so far is fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, I've edited, thank you.

Comment: Note that $e^x \ge 1 +x $ (follows from, for example, the mean value theorem), so $(e^x)^n \ge (1+x)^n$, for $ x\ge 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat, I've already proved that part, I now need to show that $\sum_{i=1}^{k}{n\choose i}\le \left(\frac{en}{k}\right)^k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can strengthen

$$\binom{n}kx^k\le(1+x)^n\le e^{nx}$$

to

$$\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{n}kx^i\le(1+x)^n\le e^{nx}\;.$$

Moreover, $0<x<1$, so $x^k\le x^i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$, and therefore

$$\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{n}ix^k\le\sum_{i=1}^k\binom{n}kx^i\le(1+x)^n\le e^{nx}\;.$$

Now argue for the last part just as you did for the previous part.